# Generative iterator that gives out references to itself

Tags: rust

For Advent of Code Day 17 (problem statement isn't super important), what I want to do is have a type:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Cubes {
    active: HashSet<Vec<i32>>,
}
```

And create an `Iterator` that yields out successive instances of that type. I can (did) implement this:

```rust
impl Iterator for Cubes {
    type Item = Cubes;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Cubes> { ... }
}
```

Which works fine, but is pretty expensive since what I end up doing is both modifying the `Cubes` locally *and also* returning a copy of it.

What I'd like do is have the `Iterator` mutate its internal state and hand out a reference to it, so that I don't need to make any copies.

Even in the most trivial case of like an infinite iterator that just hands out a reference, I can't come up with a formulation of this that checks:

```rust
// this doesn't actually compile
fn iter(cc: &mut Cubes) -> impl Iterator<Item=&Cubes> {
    std::iter::from_fn(move ||{
        Some(&*cc)
    })
}
```

whereas what I'm doing is roughly equivalent to this (which does compile, but I am trying to improve):

```rust
fn iter(cc: ConwayCubes) -> impl Iterator<Item=ConwayCubes> {
    std::iter::from_fn(move ||{
        Some(cc.clone())
    })
}
```

I suppose I could also restructure the problem to hand out something like `Rc<Cubes>`, which would still do copies but those copies would be cheap, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this with references.

Comment: So the first `next()` you return a reference to an instance of `Cubes`. Now the second `next()` you want to modify that same instance and return the same reference again? Thus any subsequent `next()` call will invalidate all the previous? If what I said is what you mean, then that is why you cannot do that.

Comment: Why not [just do this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea5ac72d2de0d1f8ee35b8d7d9f216b8)? Also like @vallentin said you can't mutate something if you have loaned out immutable references to it.

Comment: @vallentin Yeah, phrasing it that way seems impossible. But is there any way to do this sort of thing efficiently?

Comment: @pretzelhammer I actually do need mutation. I'm trying to do the sequence `x`, `f(x)`, `f(f(x))`, `f(f(f(x)))`... just without the copying.

Comment: @Barry the issue is that, supposed you did `collect()` and now have a `Vec<&Cubes>` with `4` items, then that `Vec` would _contain_ `f(f(f(x)))`, `f(f(f(x)))`, `f(f(f(x)))`, `f(f(f(x)))` and not `x`, `f(x)`, `f(f(x))`, `f(f(f(x)))`

Comment: @vallentin That's... a very good point.

Comment: It sounds more like you'd want `fn next_state(&mut self)`, then in the event you actually want to create an `Iterator` of all states over time, you could `impl IntoIterator` where you then do use `clone()`

Comment: @vallentin Can you throw that into an answer? This sounds very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that you cannot return a reference to something while subsequently wanting to mutate it. Because that something is still being "borrowed" and referenced elsewhere.

If that was possible, then suppose you [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect)ed everything into a `Vec<&Cubes>`, then if that resulted in a `Vec<&Cubes>` with 3 items. Then given that it's 3 references to the same instance, then all 3 items would have the same state as the last item.

In short you'd not end up with `x`, `f(x)`, `f(f(x))` as you want, but instead `f(f(x))`, `f(f(x))`, `f(f(x))`

---

Since you want less cloning, then it sounds more like you just want an `fn next_state(&mut self)` method. Then you could iterate and call `cubes.next_state()` which would update `cubes` to its next state, while no needless cloning would occur.

```rust
impl Cubes {
    fn next_state(&mut self) {
        ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    for _ in 0..10 {
        // do something with cubes

        cubes.next_state();
    }
}
```

Along the lines of what you already did, you could then create an `iter_states()` method using [`iter::from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html), which calls `next_state()` and returns a clone.

```rust
impl Cubes {
    fn iter_states(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Cubes> {
        let mut next = self.clone();
        iter::from_fn(move || {
            let current = next.clone();
            next.next_state();
            Some(current)
        })
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also introduce a custom `CubesIter` [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) type. Then you can [`impl IntoIterator for Cubes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) which converts `Cubes` into an `Iterator`.

```rust
struct CubesIter {
    next: Cubes,
}

impl Iterator for CubesIter {
    type Item = Cubes;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let current = self.next.clone();
        self.next.next_state();
        Some(current)
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for Cubes {
    type Item = Cubes;
    type IntoIter = CubesIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        CubesIter { next: self }
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to do:

```rust
let cubes: Cubes = ...;

for state in cubes {
    ...
}
```

Note that the above will iterate indefinitely. So you'd have to add some stop state or condition.